# How to block my site using proxy like Burp Suite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, burp, anti-debugging

I want to perform anti-debugging on my site and block the possibility of opening it using burp suite or using a proxy in the browser.
Also, is it possible to block the burp suite certificate (port swigger) so that anyone who logs in through the BURP browser will not be able to proceed?
I would love for such and other solutions, thank you
[BURP SUTIE certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEM6z.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

###### No it is not possible.

As a website you are bound to the executing browser to make sure the requests are securely transmitted and have no possibility to inspect the tls certificates.
You can only check if your site was loaded over http or https by accessing the browser location api:

```js
location.protocol
// returns "https:" or "http:"
```

Comment: And is it possible to identify the interception of requests??

Comment: As I said it is not possible.